# Reduce image sharpness and DPI

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, sharpness, dpi

Why does the sharpness of the imag decrease when I increase the DPI of an image?

Comment: What is the scenario that you are running through where you've noticed this?

Comment: What application(s) and device(s) are you using to view the exported images with increased DPI? Increasing DPI should do nothing unless you're inserting it into a desktop publishing app or other (rare) application that actually does something with the "DPI" tag in the EXIF info. How many pixels (width x height) does the image have before export? How many pixels (width x height) does the image have after export? It sounds like you're changing the resolution ( number of pixels) by forcing a different DPI into a specific linear dimension, which would involve much more than just changing "DPI".

Comment: This scenario is done in Lightroom Desktop software under Windows, for each image of any length and width when I enter the export settings for output, the default value of DPA is for example 72 if I do not change this value and  Get output When viewing that photo, the resolution and sharpness will be higher than when I take the same photo in the export settings section with higher dpi, for example, 300 output.  Finally, we have 2 images, one with 72 dpi and one with 300 dpi, but the resolution of the image is lower with dpi and the image is sharper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DPI is only meaningful for print or a physical display. If you are still seeing and printing the image at the same size, then *nothing* changes.

Now, if you change the DPI and render the image at that DPI, the image will become smaller. This will make the image look sharper just because details are smaller.

Comment: Ok, but unfortunately, when I create a high-definition DPi in Lightroom Export, the image becomes very osmotic, and when I reduce the DPI, the conditions return to the original state of the photo.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't.

Well, let's say, it doesn't if you only change the dpi without re-rendering the image.

DPI is not very meaningful for image-files, at least until you print them. 
So unless you change the pixel dimensions of an image, changing the DPI will do nothing in Photoshop other than attaching this value to the image. You can test this by disabling `resample image`.

However, if you increase the DPI and have the dimensions set to something else like mm, inches, cm etc, then you are changing the pixel dimensions of the image.

This will cause the image to be re-rendered in the new dimensions. As long as the pixel count is a multiple like x2 of the original size, this is fairly easy, but this only seldom is the case. So Photoshop has to interpret the image. The interpreter can be chosen via `Resample image`. Each option has its own merits.

This step can reduce sharpness just due to the resampling.

The secondary effect is, that sharpness is more or less another word for contrast between pixels of differing brightness. By resampling an edge that formerly transitioned from black to white in 4 pixels, it might mean that the transition now takes 8 pixels, as the resolutions was doubled.

Seen from far away, the sharpness ist the same, but if you zoom in, it looks less sharp.

For that reason, it is sometimes needed to resharpen the image after changing the pixel resolution.